# SQL : Merge two rows by some ID and keep values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm facing a relatively easy problem but I can't manage to wrap my head around a solution. Keep in mind I'm using PHP with the Laravel framework if it can makes things any easier.

I have a table filled with data like so :

```
ID | TRANSACTION_ID | BEACON_TYPE
---+----------------+---------------
 1 |       1        |  "abc"
 2 |       2        |  "def"
 3 |       2        |  "xyz"
```

and I would like to group them by transaction ID and to keep the beacon type inside the data like so:

```
ID | TRANSACTION_ID | BEACON_TYPE
---+----------------+---------------
 1 |       1        |  "abc"
 2 |       2        |  "def", "xyz"
```

I've tried using group by with no avail. Any ideas or hints on how to accomplish that? As I said earlier there might be some way to do it with Laravel Eloquent.

Comment: The result you say you're expecting is not going to be valid - the `ID` can be either 2 or 3, so you're "losing" information. Either drop the ID, or add it to the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using MySQL, the function you're looking for is `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Using Eloquent, it would look something like this:

```
$transactions = DB::table('tableName')
                  ->select('TRANSACTION_ID', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(BEACON_TYPE SEPARATOR ', ') as BEACON_TYPE'))
                  ->groupBy('TRANSACTION_ID')
                  ->get();
```

Note, if you want to change the separator, you just need to edit the `', '` to something else. The default separator is `','`.

Comment: i knew something like GROUP_CONCAT() existed but couldnt find the right wording to look for. Thank to the Stackoverflow community you never disappoint ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concatenate values of the group. Give it a `SEPARATOR` of `', '` to get the groups with comma separated values.

Your expected result is going to lose some information, since the `ID`s of the grouped row will be both 2 and 3 (in your example). So either don't select those IDs, or add them with a separate `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

The raw SQL query would be using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. The following queries use the table `foo`, replace that with your actual table name.

```sql
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(BEACON_TYPE SEPARATOR ', ') AS BEACON_TYPE
FROM foo
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_ID
```

Using Eloquent, you need to use `DB::raw()` to select the `GROUP_CONCAT()` part, as there's no Eloquent method for `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so then it becomes

```
$result = DB::table('foo')
            ->select('TRANSACTION_ID',
                      DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(BEACON_TYPE SEPARATOR ', '") as BEACON_TYPE)
            ->groupBy('TRANSACTION_ID');
```

or if you want to include the grouped IDs to, then..

```
$result = DB::table('foo')
            ->select('TRANSACTION_ID',
                      DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(BEACON_TYPE SEPARATOR ', '") as BEACON_TYPE),
                      DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR ', '") as ID)
            ->groupBy('TRANSACTION_ID');
```

Comment: Neat answer. Thanks for putting the time into this. I'll check this out and keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the data from the database and just want to use [collection functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) you can do the following:

```
    $things = $things->groupBy('TRANSACTION_ID')
            ->map(function($x) {
                $beaconTypes = $x->implode('BEACON_TYPE', ', ');
                $firstThing = $x->first();
                $firstThing['BEACON_TYPE'] = $beaconTypes;

                return $firstThing;
            });
```